# How do I validate hmac properly in nodejs for callrail API?

Tags: node.js

Not sure how to properly verify a request with the callrail API key using nodeJS

I keep getting different hex results than the example provided.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out using [How do I validate the Hmac using NodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72763485/how-do-i-validate-the-hmac-using-nodejs)

The code that validates the [example provided in the callrail documentation](https://apidocs.callrail.com/#validating-payloads) in nodejs is

```
const request_payload = {"answered":false,"business_phone_number":"","call_type":"voicemail","company_id":155920786,"company_name":"Boost Marketing","company_time_zone":"America/Los_Angeles","created_at":"2018-02-19T13:41:00.252-05:00","customer_city":"Rochester","customer_country":"US","customer_name":"Kaylah Mills","customer_phone_number":"+12148654559","customer_state":"PA","device_type":"","direction":"inbound","duration":"13","first_call":false,"formatted_call_type":"Voicemail","formatted_customer_location":"Rochester, PA","formatted_business_phone_number":"","formatted_customer_name":"Kaylah Mills","prior_calls":16,"formatted_customer_name_or_phone_number":"Kaylah Mills","formatted_customer_phone_number":"214-865-4559","formatted_duration":"13s","formatted_tracking_phone_number":"404-555-8514","formatted_tracking_source":"Google Paid","formatted_value":"--","good_lead_call_id":715587840,"good_lead_call_time":"2016-06-17T10:23:33.363-04:00","id":766970532,"lead_status":"previously_marked_good_lead","note":"","recording":"https://app.callrail.com/calls/766970532/recording/redirect?access_key=aaaaccccddddeeee","recording_duration":8,"source_name":"Google AdWords","start_time":"2018-02-19T13:41:00.236-05:00","tags":[],"total_calls":17,"tracking_phone_number":"+14045558514","transcription":"","value":"","voicemail":true,"tracker_id":354024023,"keywords":"","medium":"","referring_url":"","landing_page_url":"","last_requested_url":"","referrer_domain":"","conversational_transcript":"","utm_source":"google","utm_medium":"cpc","utm_term":"","utm_content":"","utm_campaign":"Google AdWords","utma":"","utmb":"","utmc":"","utmv":"","utmz":"","ga":"","gclid":"","integration_data":[{"integration":"Webhooks","data":null}],"keywords_spotted":"","recording_player":"https://app.callrail.com/calls/766970532/recording?access_key=aaaabbbbccccdddd","speaker_percent":"","call_highlights":[],"callercity":"Rochester","callercountry":"US","callername":"Kaylah Mills","callernum":"+12148654559","callerstate":"PA","callsource":"google_paid","campaign":"","custom":"","datetime":"2018-02-19 18:41:00","destinationnum":"","ip":"","kissmetrics_id":"","landingpage":"","referrer":"","referrermedium":"","score":1,"tag":"","trackingnum":"+14045558514","timestamp":"2018-02-19T13:41:00.236-05:00"};
const crypto = require('crypto');
const cipher = 'sha1';
const payloadstring =  JSON.stringify(request_payload);


const hash = crypto.createHmac(cipher, key)
               .update(payloadstring)
               .digest('base64');

console.log(hash);
```

This results in the proper hash response of

`UZAHbUdfm3GqL7qzilGozGzWV64=`

Comment: This - more than likely - can work with other APIs that use base64 hmac-sha1 signatures of the payload.